# Method of removing unnecessary namespaces in .NET Applications?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to remove unnecessary "using" statements from a class?

For example I might have a complex class in which I might add my own namespaces but there are also some namespaces that are added automatically by Visual Studio which I also might be using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls;
using MyApp.Models;
using MyApp.Services;
```

Is there a way to detect which namespaces are being used and which ones aren't so they can be removed?

**NOTE:** I believe this question would apply to any platform (Desktop, Phone, Web, etc).

Comment: Remove them one by one and see if your code breaks? :D

Comment: Developer Productivity Tool for Microsoft Visual Studio like ReSharper  will be very useful for such a task.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes - Visual Studio can do this for you. In the context menu in the text editor, choose Organize Usings > Remove and Sort. (You *can* just remove, but why not sort at the same time? :)

Personally I have it on a hotkey of Ctrl-Shift-U... it's a very handy feature.

As a side note, these aren't `using` *statements* - they're `using` *directives*. `using` statements are the ones which dispose of resources.

Comment: The problem with that is that it removes the default namespaces too. Which I find annoying. I don't want the `using System.Linq` to disappear even if I don't happen to use a linq method atm.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Why? If you're not using them, why would you want them? You can always use Ctrl-. to import it again later if you try to use a type within a namespace you're not currently importing.

Comment: Does that automatic importing work with extension methods? And I like having the generic collections etc. in Intellisense even if I don't use them yet.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: It doesn't appear to with just Visual Studio, but I believe that R# *does* support that. Put it this way - I use "Remove Usings" extensively, and I've *never* found it to be a problem. You can always type "Enumerable" and import that - hardly a time killer.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - Yes, I hate the cruft. Cruft isn't a big deal in small projects, but it's downright overwhelming in large ones. When I open an unfamiliar file, the first thing I notice is how clean the using `directives` are. That gives me a sense of how maintained the contents of it are.

Comment: @Ritch I dislike most of the clutter too. But in IMO the trade-off of the clutter `System`, `System.Collections.Generic` and `System.Linq` introduce compared to the reduced Intellisense makes me favour that limited clutter.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - I live in Resharper-land, where that sort of thing is added for me. The only negative is that my Alt-Enter keys are worn out.

Comment: Guess I really should buy resharper. I keep hearing good things about it.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - Our shop is split between Resharper and CodeRush. I'm (obviously) a Resharper fanboi.

Comment: Try CodeRush before you commit to Resharper.  There's also CodeRush Xpress, which is a free add-in.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Sidenote was really helpful in terms right usage of terms.

Answer (score 13):

Right click in the class -> Organize Usings -> Remove and Sort

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Right click on the usings and select 'Organise Usings->Remove Usings' Resharper does this better than VS.

Comment: Just curious... how does Resharper's version do it better?

Comment: Resharper has this great feature where it greys out unused stuff. Usings, methods, properties, arguments, etc... It's a simple keystroke combo to remove it all.

Comment: Sorry, not a drive by - I downvoted simply because there's no "Remove Usings" options directly in the right click menu.  I also don't think ReSharper does it "better" - it just removes it just like VS.

Comment: Though I have to say that if Resharper grays out the unused usings, that's pretty nice.

Comment: @Marek - Resharper greys them out so that you know when you view them. The OP asked if there was a way to detect it, that's something Resharper does better than VS.

Answer (score 2):

**How about having it automatically happen whenever you save?**

[PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99/)

Install this Microsoft-created add-in, and VS 2010 will **always** remove and sort usings every time you save a code file (e.g. with Ctrl-S or clicking a Save button).

The option is under Tools > Options > PowerCommands > Remove and Sort Usings on save.  There's also an option to automatically format the document on Save, which will make sure your code lines up, doesn't include trailing spaces, etc.

(Should you need to *avoid* removing and sorting usings while this is installed, just build or run your code without explicitly saving.  The automatic save-on-build or save-on-run will still happen.)

Comment: @Heyyou, CodeRush (which costs money) can do this but leave the namespaces you specify.  I have it always leave `System`, `System.Collections.Generic`, and `System.Linq`.